# Reconstructing chain of linked observations

Tags: stata, vlookup

I have a dataset in which firms can be owned by people (type 0) or by other firms (type 1).
Here is an example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1(firmid ownerid) str7 last_name byte type
"A" "B" ""        1
"A" "C" ""        1
"A" "D" ""        1
"B" "E" ""        1
"B" "F" ""        1
"E" "I" "Smith"   0
"E" "J" "Johnson" 0
"F" "G" ""        1
"G" "I" "Smith"   0
"G" "J" "Johnson" 0
"G" "H" ""        1
end
```

Firms can be owned by other firms which in turn are owned by other firms and so on. For example, A is owned by B, B is owned by E and F, etc. I would like to reconstruct these ownership chains until I get to the ultimate owner(s) (a person, like I or J, or a firm with no owners in the data, like C, D, or H).
The final output would look like this:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1(firmid ownerid1 ownerid2 ownerid3) str5 last_name1 str7 last_name2 byte(type1 type2 type3) str1(ultimate_owner1 ultimate_owner2 ultimate_owner3 ultimate_owner4 ultimate_owner5)
"A" "B" "C" "D" ""      ""        1 1 1 "I" "J" "H" "C" "D"
"B" "E" "F" ""  ""      ""        1 1 . "I" "J" "H" ""  "" 
"E" "I" "J" ""  "Smith" "Johnson" 0 0 . "I" "J" ""  ""  "" 
"F" "G" ""  ""  ""      ""        1 . . "I" "J" "H" ""  "" 
"G" "I" "J" "H" "Smith" "Johnson" 0 0 1 "I" "J" "H" ""  "" 
end
```

I thought `vlookup` would be a good place to start. With the following code I retrieve all intermediate and final owners (so I'm close to the goal), but the code is cumbersome and I can't see how to generalize it to an arbitrarily long ownership chain.

```
ssc inst missings
by firmid, sort: g rep=_n
reshape wide ownerid last_name share type, i(firmid) j(rep)

qui forv j=1/3{
    g rep_ownerid`j'=ownerid`j'
forv i=1/3{
    vlookup rep_ownerid`j', gen(ownerid`j'`i') key(firmid) value(ownerid`i')
forv k=1/3{
    vlookup ownerid`j'`i', gen(ownerid`j'`i'`k') key (firmid) value(ownerid`k')
forv m=1/3{
    replace ownerid`m'="99" if ownerid`m'==""
    vlookup ownerid`j'`i'`k', gen(ownerid`j'`i'`k'`m') key (firmid) value(ownerid`m')
}
}
}
}

qui foreach x of varlist ownerid* {
replace `x'="" if `x'=="99"
}

qui missings dropvars, force
drop rep*
```

I was wondering if there is a better / more general way to achieve my goal?
The original data is rather big (3M observations).